# Monotouch: BarItem badge tint color?

Tags: xamarin.ios, uitabbaritem

When I set the badge value, it's red background with white font.

Is it possible to change the background color of the badge to eg. blue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do this recently and there isn't a built-in way.

But really, it's not that hard to write your own:

- Have a graphic designer make you 3 images: left side, right side, and a 1 pixel wide image you can stretch for larger numbers
- Make a new control and inherit from UIView
- Use a UILabel and three UIImageViews for each picture

The only *slightly* difficult part is going to be measuring the length of the text for centering.

Rolling your own let's you make it exactly how you need.  I exposed a `int? Value` property that made extremely easy to use from within my apps as well as a `ValueChanged` event.